# Django redirect not working when I submit my form

Tags: django

My redirect for my login page is not working correctly when I submit a form.

```py
def login_page(request):

    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    if form.is_valid():

        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            print(request.user.is_authenticated)
            login(request, user)

            # Redirect to a success page.
            return redirect("login")
        else:
            # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
            print("Error")

    return render(request, "content/login.html", context)
```

I am expecting it to redirect to same page and print an output that lets me know the authentication worked. But this is what actually happens..

```
Page not found(404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/POST?username=stone&password=pass
```

Any idea as to what is going on?

Comment: Can you show as the view that you are requesting with "login"?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown your template, but it looks like you have `action="POST"` instead of `method="POST"` in your `form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure, that your template.html looks like this:

```
 <form method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form }}
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(reverse('homepage'))

    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
      if form.is_valid():
          user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])

          if user is not None:
              login(request, user)
              return redirect(reverse('homepage'))
          else:
              error_message = "* Password you entered is incorrect."
              return render(request, "account/login.html",{
                  "form": form,
                  "error_message": error_message,
              })
    else:
        return render(request, "account/login.html", {
            "form": form,
        })
```